# Multithreading using loop in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, pascal, rad-studio

I want to do multithreading where the threads are allocated automatically using loop (e.g for loop) in delphi. When I do so, I'm getting a Range check error or the threads are getting crashed. Below is my code. But when I run manually without looping it executes no error or crashing.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Diagnostics, System.Threading, System.Math,
  System.Classes;

var
  NumberOfThreads: Uint8;
  Tasks: array of ITask;
  SumFromThreads, InputNumber: array of cardinal;
  SW: TStopWatch;

function SumUptoNumber(NumberUptoSum: cardinal): cardinal;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for var I := 1 to NumberUptoSum do
    Result := Result + I;

end;

begin
  try
    writeln('How many threads do you want?');
    readln(NumberOfThreads);
    SW := TStopWatch.StartNew;

    SetLength(Tasks, NumberOfThreads);
    SetLength(SumFromThreads, NumberOfThreads);
    SetLength(InputNumber, NumberOfThreads);

    for var I := 0 to NumberOfThreads - 1 do
    begin
      writeln('Enter the value for ' + (I + 1).ToString);
      readln(InputNumber[I]);
      Tasks[I] := TTask.Create(
        procedure
        begin
          SumFromThreads[I] := SumUptoNumber(InputNumber[I]);
        end);
      Tasks[I].Start;
      //sleep(1);

    end;

    TTask.WaitForAll(Tasks);
    SW.Stop;

    for var J := 0 to NumberOfThreads - 1 do
      writeln('The sum upto ' + InputNumber[J].ToString +
        ' calculated using Thread Number ' + J.ToString + ' is ' +
        SumFromThreads[J].ToString);

    SetLength(Tasks, 0);
    SetLength(SumFromThreads, 0);
    SetLength(InputNumber, 0);

    writeln('Duration of this process is ' + ((SW.ElapsedMilliseconds) / 1000)
      .ToString + ' seconds ');
    readln;

  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      readln;

    end;

  end;

end.
```

Comment: What is the error, what line does it occur on? What input file are you using? I think I'd implement `SumUptoNumber` without a loop as `Result := NumberUptoSum * (NumberUptoSum+1) div 2`

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, the error occurs on TTask.WaitForAll(Tasks);

What you have mentioned is an alternate way of calculating n(n+1)/2 but I want to give some load on the computation therefor used for loop which executes fine.

The error is 'Range check Error' I guess the threads are getting crashed. Since TTask creates a thread pool initially.

Comment: The output of the release mode

How many threads do you want?
3
Enter the value for 1
10
Enter the value for 2
100
Enter the value for 3
1000
The sum upto 10 calculated using Thread Number 0 is 0
The sum upto 100 calculated using Thread Number 1 is 0
The sum upto 1000 calculated using Thread Number 2 is 0

Error:-
EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 00175E63 in module 'Sum_of_Individual_numbers_multithreading.exe'. Read of address 6A113958

But if I uncomment the sleep it works fine. I dont get why.

Comment: Why aren't you using the debugger. It's really hard to debug without it.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is variable capturing.

You are capturing the loop variable `I` in the anonymous method that you are passing to `TTask.Create`. Variable capturing **always happens by reference** and not by value.
This causes the last task to execute the callback with the value of `I` having the value it has after the loop has ended - usually it is one higher than the last value the loop body was executed with. It also causes the other tasks to possibly run with a different value than the one you expect them to because the same happens for them as for the last one - you just don't get a range check violation but simply are accessing the wrong array element.

The Sleep basically delays the loop which causes the task to likely run with the loop variable not being incremented already. This is why you won't see the issue but it does not fix the issue itself.

When using an anonymous method inside a loop and you need to use the index of the loop or basically anything that changes each loop iteration, you always need to wrap the creation of the anonymous method inside a function itself to cause multiple instances of the anonymous method with different values being captured.

Like so:

```
function CreateNewTask(I: Integer): ITask;
begin
  Result := TTask.Create(
    procedure
    begin
      SumFromThreads[I] := SumUptoNumber(InputNumber[I]);
    end);
end;
```

Comment: Also see [Anonymous Methods in Delphi](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi): [Anonymous Methods Variable Binding](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi#Anonymous_Methods_Variable_Binding) in Embarcadero's documentation.

Comment: Thank you I Implemented similar to it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Declare SumFromThreads and SumUptoNumber result as int64.

Both InputNumber and SumFromThreads are the same type, so with large enough InputNumber the sum will overflow = range check error. If you turn off range checking, you'd get a wrong result.

The other issue is probably variable capturing described by Stefan.

Comment: There is no problem with the datatypes